# Symmetric and alternating powers of defining representation of classical groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a classical groups (including $\operatorname U(n)$, $\operatorname{SO}(n)$, and $\operatorname{Sp}(2n)$), and $V$ be the defining representation (the natural inclusion of $G$ into $\operatorname{GL}(n,C)$).  When are $S^kV$ and $\bigwedge\nolimits^kV$ irreducible ?

Comment: what are $S^kV$ and $\Lambda^k  V$? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I assume V is the defining representation, and these are the symmetric and exterior powers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the decomposition of $S^kV$ and $\Lambda^k V$ into a direct sum of irreducible representations in Table 5 in the book: Onishchik and Vinberg, Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups, Springer-Verlag 1990.

Instead of $U(n)$ you can consider its complexification ${\rm GL}(n,{\Bbb C})$. Then both $S^k V$ and $\Lambda^k V$ are irreducible.

For ${\rm SO}(n)$, the representations $\Lambda^k V$ are irreducible for $k\neq n/2$, while $S^k V$ are reducible for all $k>1$ (indeed, for $k=2$ we know that $S^2 V$ contains the trivial representation).

For ${\rm Sp}(2n)$, the representations  $S^k V$ are irreducible, while $\Lambda^k V$ are reducible for $1<k<2n-1$ (indeed, for $k=2$ we know that $\Lambda^2 V$ contains the trivial representation).